# Is there multidb support available in Doctrine?

Tags: php, database, zend-framework, doctrine, zend-db

I was evaluating Doctrine to use with Zend Framework in one of upcoming project.

The biggest concern is multidb support.

Does Doctrine offer the multidb support in the same way Zend Framework does?

Please help me in taking the descision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how Zend Frameworks handles multiple database connections but here's how it's done in Doctrine: http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/connections/en

However, I'd consider using Doctrine2 instead of Doctrine 1.x. It's better performing. In Doctrine2 you simply use different Entity Manager for each of the connections.

Comment: Thx Kuba for your suggestion. I went through the documentation and it seems that Doctrine 2 is quite powerful. I will consider Doctrine 2.